# Unity2D how to detect two objects are colliding from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to detect 2 different if objects are colliding but I have to do this from different scripts.

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){}
```

With this function, I can't define the object. It takes the object that attached to script. How can I change the `Collision2D collision` ? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unity does not offer such a feature directly unfortunately. Probably has to do with achieving an efficient implementation on the side of the physics engine.
The usual solution is to add a script with the usual OnCollision functions to the respective objects and also give that script a reference to the 3rd object which shall be notified about the event.
Through the reference you just call a public function in that object.

If only one instance of the 3rd Object exists, this can be improved by using the Singleton pattern on the 3rd object to make it accessible without a reference.